# Move a polygon in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

so I'm trying to make a program where a circle solves a maze. I can raw the maze so far, and can give the circle the coordinates to move to, but I'm very new to Tkinter and not sure how I can make it so the circle moves (say every 2s). At the moment all it does is show the first case, and I don't think I'm putting the `top.mainloop()` where it should be.
Code (abridged to ficus on the GUI):

```
import string
import random
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from enum import Enum

class Direction(Enum):
    up=1
    down=2
    left=3
    right=4
myFile = open("labyrinth.txt","r")
lab=myFile.read()
"get number of lines/rows & columns: LABYRINTH MUST BE SQUARE"
cols=rows=len(lab.splitlines())
"GUI"
"build the output window"
top = Tk()
C = Canvas(top, bg = "white", height = rows*40, width = cols*40)
lab=lab.splitlines()
maze=[]
for i in range(rows):
    maze.append([0]*(cols))
for y in range (rows):
    for x in range (cols):
        maze[y][x]=lab[y][x]
        if(maze[y][x]=="1"):
            myColor="white"
        elif(maze[y][x]=="0"):
            myColor="black"
        elif(maze[y][x]=="3"):
            myColor="red"
        else:
            myColor="green"
        C.create_polygon(x*40, y*40, x*40+40, y*40, x*40+40 ,y*40+40, x*40, y*40+40, fill=myColor)
robot=C.create_oval(0, 0, 40, 40, fill="yellow")
C.pack()
top.mainloop()
d=Direction.down   
"move"
dest=[]
dest=position  
while(stepsTaken<nbMaxSteps):
    dest=[]
    dest.append(position[0]) #x does not change
    dest.append(position[1]-1) #y decreases by 1
    top.after(2000, C.move(robot, dest[0]*40, dest[1]*40))
```

Where am I going wrong?
Apologies if this has already been asked, I did search but couldn't find an answer about  where the `top.mainloop()` should be.

Comment: You should instead make a recursive method as opposed to a `while` loop. Then call it once before `mainloop`.

Comment: Please note that the code above has indentation error. Also is incomplete in the sense that one cannot simply c/p and run it.

Comment: @Nae I fixed the indents and gave you my whole code so you can c/p.

Comment: Would a recursive method work for the GUI? Why not a `while` though?

Comment: It would with `after` method. while may be troublesome as it blocks GUI updates while it is running, and if it takes too long GUI will be unresponsive in the meantime. Alternatively, you can run a while loop on another thread.

Comment: You shouldn't paste your entire code either, please provide [mcve] For the problem specifically. I thought you'd know this already, sorry.

Comment: @Nae, my bad, I know the rules but I was in a rush and there is so much overlap between different sections, I just pasted the whole thing to save time, at least I know it works